# Putting a core-pages inside another core-pages makes internal core-pages always visible

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

I'm putting a core-pages element inside another core-pages element, but the internal core-pages element remains always visible.

Here the HTML code:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_pages.html">

<polymer-element name="pages-test">
  <template>

      <button on-click={{increasePages}}>pages</button>
      <button on-click={{increaseSubPages}}>sub-pages</button>

        <core-pages selected={{selectedPages}}>
           <div>PAGE 1</div>
           <div>PAGE 2</div>
           <div>PAGE 3
             <core-pages selected={{selectedSubPages}}>
               <div>SUB PAGE 1</div>
               <div>SUB PAGE 2</div>
               <div>SUB PAGE 3</div>
             </core-pages>   
           </div>
        </core-pages>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="pages_test.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

And the Dart code:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('pages-test')
class PagesTest extends PolymerElement {

  @observable
  int selectedPages = 0;

  @observable
  int selectedSubPages = 0;

  PagesTest.created() : super.created() {
  }

  void increasePages() {
    selectedPages = (selectedPages + 1)%3;
  }

  void increaseSubPages() {
    selectedSubPages = (selectedSubPages + 1)%3;
  }

}
```

When `PAGE 1` is visible also `SUB PAGE 1` is visible.

I'm using the core-pages in the correct way? There is any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this is because visibility is applied using CSS depending on the `core-selected` class. The CSS selector seems to include children too.

This CSS fixed it

```dart
  core-pages > :not(.core-selected) > core-pages > .core-selected {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

A workaround in code is to set `selectedSubPages` to `-1` when `selectedPages` != `2`

The code looks like

```dart
  @observable
  int selectedPages = 0;

  int _selectedSubPages = 0;
  @ComputedProperty('selectedPages')
  int get selectedSubPages {
    if (selectedPages != 2) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return _selectedSubPages;
    }
  }
  set selectedSubPages(int value) => _selectedSubPages = value;


  void increasePages() {
    selectedPages = (selectedPages + 1)%3;
  }

  void increaseSubPages() {
    selectedSubPages = notifyPropertyChange(#selectedSubPages, selectedSubPages, (selectedSubPages + 1)%3);
  }
```

you can also try to fix it using CSS to make the page only visible if the parent also is active (probably a nicer solution).

Comment: Sorry, it was the `core-selected` class not the `active` attribute. I changed my answer. I also added an example how to workaround in code.

Comment: I also added a CSS-solution - very simple :-)

Comment: Do you think should we open an issue?

Comment: Yes I think this could be fixed very easily in the `<core-pages>` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It mysteriously went away (the nested core-page was hidden when not selected) when I put the core-pages in the main content area of a core-scaffold.